# firebase realtime database how to write rules to only apply the web app to write data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm writing a very simple webapp.

I only want the webapp to be able to write into the firebase's realtime database.

I am not able to find any instructions about only allowing webapp to write data.

Comment: I have an idea, change it to only allow writes when you supply a certain header or piece of authentication, and then only send that piece of authentication or header from the web app

Comment: hi @DaMahdi03 that sounds good to me. Could you please demo how you achieve it? thanks

Comment: @DaMahdi03 how can I write the database rule on Firebase's Rules section in which I can access to the request's header and check whether it has that specific value?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict access to Firebase to only calls coming from the web app through security rules. The Firebase configuration data is freely findable (by design) and you should assume that everyone can make whatever calls they want against the API with your configuration data.

There is no way to pass request headers into security rules. But even if there was, anyone with access to your web app could find the values you pass in the header and copy them into their own API calls.

While it **is** possible to restrict writes to a specific path, where the user must know a dynamic part of that path, if you then put that dynamic path in the code of your web app, anyone with access to the web app can copy that path and use it in API calls themselves.

The proper way to secure your database is to use Firebase Authentication to sign the user in (there's anonymous authentication in case you don't want the user to have to provide credentials), and then use the known identity of the user (`auth.uid` in security rules) to control what data they can access.